# Android:Trigger action with SMS

Tags: java, android

I have simple application which get gps coordinates on a click of a button.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Coordinates extends Activity {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0, 
                0,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );

        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });        

    }    

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(Coordinates.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }   

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

    }

}
```

I also made SmsReceiver class which receives SMS:

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
if (bundle != null) {
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
if (msgs.length >= 0) {
msgs[0] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
String message = msgs[0].getMessageBody().toString();
if (message.toString().matches("GPS")){



    Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

else
{Toast.makeText(context,"Nothing",100 ).show();
}


}
}
}
}
```

Everything works fine, but my question is, how to trigger gps to display coordinates 
with specific **SMS** instead of a **button**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you have a receiver and you also have a method to show the GPS coordinates why not introduce them to each other? That is, call your showCurrentLocation(); instead of showing GPS toast

Comment: Thanks alex for your respond. I thought of that too. I put Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
coordinates.showCurrentLocation();   but for some reason I am getting null pointer exception error.

Comment: I managed to put Broadcastreceiver as inner class and application is working, but I have another problem. I am trying to run this application after phone boots up but with no luck. I tried with receiver and boot_up_completed method but still nothing. I have no service in my application so maybe that is the problem. Please help, I am stuck with this one.

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup